# Second drive shared network folder lost after reboot

Tags: networking, reboot, sharing

I am able to share a folder sitting on a second drive over the network. After rebooting the share is lost and has to be redone. Is there any way of ensuring it remains permanent?

Comment: Correction - second drive

Comment: you can simply [edit] your post to make corrections. This makes it easier for others to follow ;-)

Answer (score 0):

On my system, I used the Disks utility and edited the mounting options for the "other" partitions. They were being mounted under my profile. I changed the settings to turn Automatic Mount Options off, and then entered a new mount point under a common part of the file system - in my case I used /media/data, but something under /mnt or a different path under /media should work fine as well. After saving these settings, and remounting the partitions, I recreated the shares, and then rebooted. After reboot, the shares were still there.